# isomorphisms of $\pi_{1}(T^2, x_{0})$ with itself.

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I1m studying fundamental group and its relation with covering maps, I was thinking about an exercise:
every isomorphism of $\pi_{1}(T^2, x_{0})$ with itself is induced by a homomorphism $f:T^2 \rightarrow T^2$ . $T^2 = S^1 \times S^1.$

I probably have to use a matrix with integer entries and induce a continus function, but I don't know hou to that.

Comment: First:  Can you describe the form of every isomorphism of $\pi_1(T^2)$?

Comment: it is a linear transformation with integer entries..

Comment: But not all matrices correspond to isomorphisms.  As a trivial example, the $0$ matrix doesn't give an isomorphism of $\pi_1(T^2)$.  As a further hint, neither does the matrix consisting of all $1$s.  So, what's the missing condition?

Comment: they need to be invertible.. But how can I induce a continuous function on torus with them?

Comment: One final condition (which you maybe be thinking already) - they must be invertible in $\mathbb{Z}$, which is a much stronger condition than being invertible in $\mathbb{R}$.  As far as your next question is concerned, think of $T^2$ as $S^1\times S^1$ which each $S^1$ thought of as the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$.  Now, consider functions of the form $f(z,w) = (z^a w^b, z^c w^d)$.